# Stop <div> moving on jQuery ui droppable drop event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Here is what I'm talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/m5Tse/1/

When I drop the draggable, it changes the position of the div droppable on the page.  It seems like there should be a simple solution, but I can't seem to figure it out nor ask google the proper question.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to just be a CSS issue.

Try to change your `.box` to `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`

```
.box{
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    float:left;
    ...
```

Change your dropbox css to reflect the following:

```
.dropbox{
    /*height: 100%;*/
    height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add relative position to the .box and add absolute to .dropbox, and then make .dropbox explicitly fill .box with width and height.

```
.box{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1pt solid black;
}

.dropbox{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}​
```

I tested it on your js-fiddle and it worked for me.